# QML: Behavior on property does not recognize number variable

Tags: qt, qml

I'm trying [this](https://github.com/rafzby/circular-progressbar) short code:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

Item {
    id: root

    property int size: 450
    property int lineWidth: 25
    property real value: 0

    property color primaryColor: "#29b6f6"
    property color secondaryColor: "#e0e0e0"
    property int animationDuration: 1000

    width: size
    height: size

    onValueChanged: {
        canvas.degree = value * 360;
    }

    Canvas {
        id: canvas

        property real degree: 0.0

        anchors.fill: parent
        antialiasing: true

        onDegreeChanged: {
            requestPaint();
        }

        onPaint: {
            var ctx = getContext("2d");

            var x = root.width / 2;
            var y = root.height / 2;

            var radius = root.size / 2 - root.lineWidth
            var startAngle = (Math.PI / 180) * 270;
            var fullAngle = (Math.PI / 180) * (270 + 360);
            var progressAngle = (Math.PI / 180) * (270 + degree);

            ctx.reset()

            ctx.lineCap = 'round';
            ctx.lineWidth = root.lineWidth;

            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(x, y, radius, startAngle, fullAngle);
            ctx.strokeStyle = root.secondaryColor;
            ctx.stroke();

            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(x, y, radius, startAngle, progressAngle);
            ctx.strokeStyle = root.primaryColor;
            ctx.stroke();
        }

        Behavior on degree {
            NumberAnimation {
                duration: 1000
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It works fine only if I comment out the `Behavior` object.
When it is there I get a runtime error and the program exits:

> qrc:/CircularProgressBar.qml:-1 - qrc:/CircularProgressBar.qml: Invalid property assignment: number expected

I'm using Qt 5.15.10 and the official [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-behavior.html) report a similar example.
I get the same error even if leave only the declaration of `Behavior`:

```
Behavior on degree {
    /*NumberAnimation {
        duration: 1000
    }*/
}
```

But `degree` *is* a number. Why it says it expects a number?

Comment: I tried running your code on `qt5.15.2-win-mingw`, and there were no runtime errors. The code is working fine.

Comment: BTW, don't use canvas in QML. It consumes too many resources. Instead, try using [`Shape`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-shapes-shape.html) or [`ShaderEffect`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-shadereffect.html).